# Should new challenges on Codidact be posted into The Nineteenth Byte?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat, rss

[Codidact](https://codidact.com/) is a related network of sites to Stack Exchange, created in the aftermath of [behaviour by Stack Exchange in late 2019](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/355458), in an effort to [create a better Q&A network](https://meta.codidact.com/posts/276296). One of the sites in their network is [Code Golf](https://codegolf.codidact.com/), where a [large number of CGCC users](https://codegolf.codidact.com/users) have started to contribute. The site has significantly less activity than this site, and so users often [advertise](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=58177257#58177257) their new challenges posted there in [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte).

Recently, [bobble](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/463092) suggested [adding a TNB feed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58328325#58328325) for new Codidact challenges via their [RSS feed](https://codegolf.codidact.com/categories/49/feed.rss). Codidact currently gets around one challenge every 5 days<sup>[1]</sup> (compared to our 25 per week<sup>[2]</sup>), so this is unlikely to be disruptive to the room, and would increase activity for challenges on their site.

However, Codidact is a [competitor to SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364556/the-future-of-community-promotion-open-source-and-hot-network-questions-ads#comment1216865_364556), and is a completely separate site. We've [rejected](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7079/do-we-want-xkcd-autposted-in-chat) proposals to have feeds for non-CGCC related posts, and currently, all [3](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21931/66833) [bots](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22365/66833) and [4 feeds](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/240/the-nineteenth-byte?tab=feeds) operating in The Nineteenth Byte all post CGCC posts.

Therefore, I believe this would benefit from a community discussion, answering:

- Should new challenges posted on Codidact be posted into The Nineteenth Byte?
- Should [Codidact Sandbox](https://codegolf.codidact.com/categories/50) and/or [Codidact Meta](https://codegolf.codidact.com/categories/48) questions be posted into The Nineteenth Byte?

---

<sub>[1]: [This](https://codegolf.codidact.com/posts/281368) was posted close to 2 months ago on Codidact. Since then, they've had [11 challenges](https://codegolf.codidact.com/categories/49?sort=age), making ~5 days between challenges</sub>

<sub>[2]: We [currently have](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday) around 3.5 questions/day, making 24.5 questions/week</sub>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Yes - challenges should be posted

For those of us who want to participate more actively on Codidact (including myself, and I know of a couple of others), this is a good reminder or a good way to let us know about challenges that we can go <s>FGITW in golfing languages</s> think about and solve with our very high IQ and brainpower.

I often forget about Codidact and forget to check it out because I don't feel as much of a community sense as when I'm here with y'all especially in chat. It doesn't draw me back in the same way, but I would like to participate there. This is not only a good way to remind individuals of it but a way to spur discussion on it, and getting more people to talk about a new challenge or new ideas together is a way to build that community portion that's missing and build that critical mass.

For the record, I do not intend for Codidact to replace SE. For reasons that are probably not very difficult to see, I am not advocating ditching SE, or that we should move our whole community there. I am simply saying that for those of us who want to *also* participate there *on top of* here, it gives incentive, spawns discussion, and acts as a reminder.

---

For those of us who don't care, we can just ignore it. Sort of how you can just ignore a sandbox post that's been oneboxed. TNB follows the rule that "off-topic stuff is fine until on-topic discussion starts", so Codidact-related discussions are of a lower priority, so you don't have to worry about it cutting off important topics or conversations as a mod or RO should rule that that discussion should go to another room or over to Codidact itself.

---

However, I am not sure about meta or the sandbox. For now, I am not voting on that. It would be a good idea to create those as separate answers to vote for, so that people can vote on them independently.

Answer (score 4):

### No - meta posts should *not* be posted

Everything that feeds into TNB should have some connection to Code Golf Stack Exchange. Old Sandbox Posts connects to our Sandbox, which is part of our site. Our other seven feeds / bot configurations all connect to bounties on our site, meta (which is about our site), challenges to our site, answers to a challenge on our site, etc.

Cross-posting challenges from Codidact makes sense because it connects to the *Code Golf* part of our site, and presumably everyone on *Code Golf Stack Exchange* is interested in *Code Golf*.

However, Codidact Meta is connected to Code Golf Codidact, and not to either *Code Golf* or *Stack Exchange*, and thus I believe it would be off-topic for a feed into TNB.

If there is interest, a chat room could be created regarding Codidact discussion, and then all of these feeds would make a lot of sense to go there, but I don't think a feed from their meta should be put here, because the average person will probably be interested (or at least not really disinterested) in a code golf challenge on another site, but probably not so much a (meta) discussion regarding another site.

Answer (score 4):

### Codidact Sandbox posts should *not* be posted

The Codidact Sandbox is a bit of a grey area in my opinion - posts there are more relevant to us than posts to their meta, but less relevant than their challenges. However, I don't think it is necessary to post Codidact Sandbox posts automatically into The Nineteenth Byte.

I can just about justify Codidact main as growing a partner site to us, and increasing exposure to a site users here will be interested in. Stack Exchange may consider Codidact to be a competitor, but a lot of us treat it more as an additional place to go golfing.

However, CGCC is not Codidact. Codidact has its own [chat](https://discord.gg/bv2aaGa), is an independent site, and I for one don't want the two sites to effectively become dependent on either the other one. I think its perfectly appropriate for users to ask for feedback on their Codidact Sandboxed posts in TNB, and I'm not opposed to having a feed/bot into [The Guild of Reviewers](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123403/the-guild-of-reviewers). But I don't think these posts should be posted into The Nineteenth Byte, as they are (IMO) not relevant enough to deserve more feed clutter